# Не понимаю в классах python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Итак есть три класса. Скажем А, B, С - они как подпрограммы. Создаем класс майн.

В майн пишем:

```
    import A
    import B
    class ASR:
    
      def rr(self):
         self.a = A() #например подключаем класс конфига
         self.b = B() #например подключаем класс бд

   ASR.rr()
```

Примеры:

```py
    class A:
        
        def config_run(self):
            self.config = ConfigUpdater()
    
            if not (os.path.isfile('config.ini')):
                cnf ="connect = :memory:"
                self.config.read_string(cnf)
```

```py
    class B():
    def connect(self,connect):
    
       if a.get_value('connect') != ":memory:":
```

Как из А обратится к методам или атрибутам b, ну или наоборот? Передавать в качестве параметра к методам в инит?

Когда классы в одном файле, то через глобальную переменную хорошо выходит. А как это сделать из файлов классов я тупо не понимаю. Если делать через наследование - то пишет что вы получаете цикличность, импортируя майн в классе А.

Comment: никак. а зачем ASR?

Comment: Данный код нерабочий, он даже не запустится. Приведите тот код, с которым у вас возникли проблемы - например, как у вас в одном файле, и опишите что конкретно вы хотите сделать.

Comment: Да, и в Python файл != класс (в отличие от Java, например)

Comment: почитайте про [импорт модулей](https://younglinux.info/oopython/module)

Comment: @TigerTV.ru прочитал, и скажем честно это запутало.... Почему когда в одном файле классы, то создание экземпляра класса прекрасно работает через глобальную переменную. Когда пытаешься эти классы имортировать из  файлов - то получается прям какой-то квест))))
ASR - это просто пример.

Comment: Решил уже просто кидать созданный экземпляр классу, чтобы внутри его подхватывал...

Comment: вы сейчас пытаетесь понять код который вы не написали. Попробуйте упростить себе задачу и написать простые классы с простыми методами (method1, method2) и добится чтобы в связке с import это у вас заработало.

Comment: @SHKEd, у вас `a` и `b` не являются полями класса, они просто временные переменные в функции `rr`, чтобы они стали полями класса, нужно использовать `self.`: `self.a = ` и `self.b = `

Comment: @TigerTV.ru код написан. Просто сейчас пришел тот момент, когда у меня все написано в одном файле, все четыре класса. Пришло время разбить его на модули - а то я полчаса листаю где править, и тут я понял что не хрена не понимаю - почему из модуля 1 нельзя обратится в модуль 2, когда они импортированы в майн. Сначала думал, наследовавать - но получается полная фигня, так как нельзя импортировать майн в модуль 1 - так как получится цикличность. Остается только делать экземпляр модуля 1 и передавать в модуль 2, ну или наоборот - как параметры методов

Comment: @gil9red я пробовал. Тут написано просто для примера, могу подправить на self. Сути это не меняет, я не могу в одном классе, вызвать метод другого класса, или атрибута - как например. если бы эти классы были бы прописаны в одном файле. Они идут как классы там, и проще с ними работать, через ту же глобальный экземпляр, или же через атрибуты родительского класса, если определены там как экземпляры.

Comment: '''Как из А обратится к методам или атрибутам b, ну или наоборот? ''' может я ошибусь, но это нарушение принципа инкапсуляции и стоит добавить наследование ?

Comment: @Интик - не получится) наследование в модуль 1 и модуль 2 главного файла - приведет к зацикливанию, так как они определены в майне) Я просто чуток не понимаю разницу между объявленными классами в одном файле и импортирование их как модулей)))) Отсюда мой грабл в мозгах)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте выполнить сначала простой import, у вас проблемы именно с этим:

main.py

```py
from class_a import A
from class_b import B

a = A()
b = B()

b.method1(a) # 5
b.method2()  # 5
b.method3(a)
b.method4()  # 5
```

class_a.py

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.i = 5
```

class_b.py

```py
from class_a import A

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.i = 7

    def method1(self, a):
        print(a.i)

    def method2(self):
        a = A()
        print(a.i)

    def method3(self, a):
        self.a = a
        
    def method4(self):
        print(self.a.i)
```

Comment: Вот и ответ. то есть передавать как параметр в метод модуля) Я так и пытаюсь сейчас сделать.

Просто мне нужно было понять, что модули это не классы. Когда классы в одном файле - то, обращение к другому классу или его атрибуту можно через глобальную видимость.

Спасибо

Comment: @SHKEd, можно один раз передать в качестве аргумента объект, а не каждый раз и затем использовать методы или свойства объекта.(method3 и method4)

Comment: Да я так и делаю, благодарю - теперь все по полочкам в мозгу) Просто смутили модули) Хотел раздробить свой файл - теперь приходится менять логику)) Я просто ожидал что импорт будет работать как инклуд файлов)